# getAdapterPosition returning -1 always

Tags: android, kotlin

i am using groupie library and its adapter to manage my RecyclerView. i have a list of usernames and messages but whenever i use 
adapter.getAdapterPosition it returns -1 i check for the item and it is right 
com.example.myapplication.classes.Message@9a582a9

tried searching everywhere on this forum but couldn't find a solution
here is a piece of my code (using kotlin)

```
val listOfLastMessages = mutableMapOf<String,ChatLogMessages>()

  testButton.setOnClickListener {
// "4VOPV7TR7SWtrIn8s4hnZ6JBaAV2" is a user in my FirebaseDatabase, and olderLatestMessage is not returning null 

            val olderLatestMessage :Message? = listOfLastMessages["4VOPV7TR7SWtrIn8s4hnZ6JBaAV2"]
            println("Position: "+adapter.getAdapterPosition(messageRow(olderLatestMessage!!)).toString())
        }

class messageRow(private val LatestMessage :Message ) :Item<ViewHolder> () {

    override fun getLayout(): Int {return R.layout.message_main_row }

    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) { }

}
```

my Message class

```
class Message(var from_uid:String = "",var to_uid:String = "",var message:String = "",var timeStamp:Long = -1) {

}
```

i just removed some of the code to make it easier to spot my problem, my rows are showing right, but i need to check the position of a specific user row but its always returning -1. if you need any further explanation i can provide

thanks in advance.

edit: library: https://github.com/lisawray/groupie

Comment: getAdapterPosition isn't a function of RecyclerView.Adapter.  If you're using some library, you need to tag or link it-  its not like you're using a super common one everyone knows.

Comment: done. i added a link to my post

Comment: You can't instantiate a new ViewHolder/Item and expect it to be in your Adapter for you to find. I can't tell what list you've passed to the adapter, but that's where you would get the position from, such as `messagesList.indexOf(someMessage)`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't have a messagesList for all my messages, i have map for it and i am getting all these messages from FirebaseDatabase , i thought i could get the item i created before for a row and use it in getAdapterPosition, which must have an item as argument?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by changing this

```
val listOfLastMessages = mutableMapOf<String,ChatLogMessages>()
```

to that:

```
val listOfLastMessages = mutableMapOf<String,Group>()
```

and adding a groupie group inside of it